# what does 'corpus_count' in gensim word2vec?

Tags: nlp, gensim, word2vec

I want to train my word Embedding from scratch and I use gensim.models.word2vec as my model.
My corpus is so large that I can not read it at once , so I divide my corpus file into **many parts** and train my model iteratively。I find this is helpful:

```
train(corpus_iterable=None, corpus_file=None, total_examples=None, total_words=None, epochs=None, start_alpha=None, end_alpha=None, word_count=0, queue_factor=2, report_delay=1.0, compute_loss=False, callbacks=(), **kwargs)
```

### I confused about the parameter "total_words" .
Is it means total words of all my corpus or the part corpus trained now?

UPDATE:

my code is like this:

```
model =  gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec.load(init_model)  
for i in range(parts):
    model.build_vocab(corpus_file=this_part_file_name, update=True)
    model.train(corpus_file = this_part_file_name, 
                   total_words=word_count(this_part_file_name) )
```

Should the parameter total_words be `word_count(this_part_file_name)` or `word_count(ALL_my_corpus_file)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`total_words` is the count of all raw words in the sentences in the corpus. You only have to provide one of the two: `total_examples` or `total_words`. If you ran `build_vocab()`, you may get the value for total words from `model.corpus_total_words`.
There is another count - `word_count` that refers to the count of words that are already trained. You can set this to 0 if you want to train on all the words, but this is optional.

More info: https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  But I still  have some questions .  If all my corpus file contains one bilion sentences and  I divide it into 100 parts for training iteratively, it means that one piece contains 10 milion sentences, So when I train the model, total_words should be  the words of ALL my corpus file or just this part?

Comment: @xxliu If I understood correctly, you should be using the count of words in ```this_part_file_name```,  you could use ```model.word_count``` for your word count.